# Need to find out which type of radial shaft seal I have

Tags: suspension, part-identification, yamaha, seal, oil-seal

I am repairing the coilover of a Yamaha XT600 2kf and I need to replace a radial shaft seal. Unfortunately I have not been able to identify the exact type of seal this is. I have only been able to find the standard ones like this:

[image]

These are some images of the one I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey4Z7.jpg

As you can see a standard radial shaft seal will not fit. I would like to know what this type of seal is called and where I can find them.
Thanks in advance.

Update:
[image]
[image]
These measurements correspond to the markings on the seal. The markings are :BJ-14 25 7-25. Searching for the markings on google did not lead to any useful results.

Comment: Going on your image, I would suggest that what you are calling a seal is actually a dust cover, perhaps there is a different seal underneath.

Comment: I have added some information to the original question. I am certain that this is indeed a seal. The material and the markings are typical of radial shaft seals, this is just a special form or type.

Comment: Then I would take it to a specialist bearing / seal supplier who could help.

Answer (score 0):

There is this site that may help: grainger.com/mobile/category/rotary-shaft-seals/bearings/power-transmission/ecatalog/N-kz2Z1z0nx5v